# Can 180 days Spanish student visa holder depart from another Schengen state?

Tags: visas, international-travel, spain, eu

I'm an Indian on a 180 days Spanish student visa. I would like to travel around EU. Is it possible for me to catch my return flight to India from an airport in a different Schengen state or do I strictly have to depart from Spain?

Answer (score 0):

your visa is valid in all schengen countries, so can return to india from where you want.